No localisation when I publish in TestFlight
My apps works perfectly when I launch it from simulator or test device, but when I publish it in Testflight, I have an issue with all textes. No translation.
Hello, I need an help.
It's my first application and publishing. I developed my application in 2 languages, English by default and French. In the simulator or on 1 device via Xcode, everything works. In Xcode everything seems good.

2 languages in project info and my App Target in Target membership

2 languages in Localizable.xcstrings and green

Localizable.xcstrings added in Target / Build Phase / Copy Bundle Resources

I also tried to add in my app.plist
<key>CFBundleLocalizations</key> <array> <string>en</string> <string>fr</string>


In App Store Connected

both languages declared, also in Testflight.

But...nothing, when I install the application thought TestFlight, no language. The application showing the label coded in swift. I found only one relevant post but not working for me. What am I missing.
Thanks in advance for any help.

If you go to Settings > General > Language & Region on the device, is one of the app languages listed as a preferred language? Also check the settings for the app, can you choose the language to use?

I have both languages ​​and whatever which one I choose the result is the same. Same thing if I change the language of the device. On the same device if I test from xcode, no problem.
